# Angular 5 @Input an array for ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I create a list of objects, which I want to send to a target component to display.
The object is called a menuItem:

```
export class menuItem {
  title: string;
  link: string;

  constructor(Title: string, Link: string) {
    this.title = Title;
    this.link = Link;
  }
}
```

The 'home' component fills the array like this:

```
  options: Array<menuItem>;

  constructor() {
    this.options = new Array<menuItem>();
    let option = new menuItem('first', '/sample');
    this.options.push(option);
    option = new menuItem('second', '/another');
    this.options.push(option);
  }
```

then home sends it to a target in home's html:

```
<demo menu={{options}}></demo>
or
menu='options' or menu=[options] or ...
```

Demo would like to do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let m of options">
  {{m.title}} = {{m.link}}
  <a [ngStyle]="{'margin': '15px 20px'}" routerLink={{m.link}} >{{m.title}}</a>
</div>
```

But Angular complains: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `[menu]='options'`?

Comment: Obviously I haven't because that work... If you post it as an answer, I'll check it as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: More generally, the `{{}}` syntax should only be used for displaying text in the view.  It won't work properly for objects (like an array), and even if the data is a string it shouldn't be used for property binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template syntax you need to use in this situation is below.

```
[menu]='options'
```

This is how you bind the value in `options` to the property named `menu`.

Glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [] while using input parameter, using annotations  **`{{}}`**  mainly used for two way data binding

```
<demo [menu]='options'></demo>
```